# can't record app preview with qt - missing iPhone as an option

Tags: iphone, macos, quicktime

I've upgraded to 10.10 on my iMac.  I've connected my iPhone6 running 8.1 with a lightning cable.  But when I go in to quicktime to record the iPhone screen the iPhone doesn't show as an option.

[image: Screen Recording with missing iPhone6]

I can't think of anything else to try. It sees it as a microphone, so it is connected.  I can do other things with my phone connected like install development apps.  Any idea why it's not showing up here?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to choose New Movie Recording instead of New Screen Recording.  Thanks to someone in the apple dev forums for helping me find that.